# GCC optimization: how can less operations be slower?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

While trying to benchmark some options for my code (using 128 bit integers or not) I observed a behavior I just can't understand. Could anybody shed some light on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int a, char** b)
{
    printf("Running tests\n");

    clock_t start = clock();
    unsigned __int128 t = 13;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < (1UL<<30); i++)
        t += 23442*t + 25;
    if(t == 0) printf("0\n");
    printf("u128, +25, took %fs\n", double(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    start = clock();
    t = 13;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < (1UL<<30); i++)
        t += 23442*t;
    if(t == 0) printf("0\n");
    printf("u128, no+, took %fs\n", double(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    start = clock();
    unsigned long u = 13;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < (1UL<<30); i++)
        u += 23442*u + 25;
    if(u == 0) printf("0\n");
    printf("u64 , +25, took %fs\n", double(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    start = clock();
    u = 13;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < (1UL<<30); i++)
        u += 23442*u;
    if(u == 0) printf("0\n");
    printf("u64 , no+, took %fs\n", double(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

(Note that the printf are here so that gcc does not optimize out the for loop)
On my system, this reliably produces the following output:

```
u128, +25, took 2.411922s
u128, no+, took 1.799805s
u64 , +25, took 1.797960s
u64 , no+, took 2.454104s
```

While the 128 bit integer behavior makes sense, I fail to see how the 64 bit loop with less operations performs significantly (30%) slower.

Is that a known behavior? What would be the general rule when trying to benefit from this optimization when writing loops of this kind?

Edit: the behavior is only observed when compiling with -O3 option.

```
gcc -lstdc++ -O3 -o a main.cpp

u128, +25, took 2.413949s
u128, no+, took 1.799469s
u64 , +25, took 1.798278s
u64 , no+, took 2.453414s

gcc -lstdc++ -O2 -o a main.cpp

u128, +25, took 2.415244s
u128, no+, took 1.800499s
u64 , +25, took 1.798699s
u64 , no+, took 1.348133s
```

Comment: Also provide the compiler optimization settings you used when you compiled your example.

Comment: I get similar results as @user6292850 with GCC 5.3, default, with `-O`, and with `-O2`. With `-O3` though I do see the weird behaviour.

Comment: The stock answer -- look at the generated assembly code and try to make sense of it.

Comment: For 'no+',  `clang` is 10-20 times faster in my environment. `gcc` try to SIMD-vectorize in a crazy way, which results worse.

Comment: Edited original post with MWE. Behavior is observed when compiling with O3 and not with O2. Apparently O3 just slows down the 64 bit no plus loop for some reason.

Comment: Note: with `-mtune=generic` (the default on my distro), I see the big difference you're seeing, with `-mtune=intel` or `-mtune=native`, the difference is *much* smaller. (That doesn't answer the question, u64 +25 is still slightly faster, hence only a comment.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loop is so tight that dependency stall, ALU busy etc comes to play and dominate the timing. The result is thus not reliable and more sensitive to other factors than actual instruction execution.

Note that +25 can be calculated in parallel along with the multiply.

---

PS. My result on 4970K:

```
gcc version 5.2.1 20151010
gcc -lstdc++ -O2 -o a a.cpp

u128, +25, took 1.346360s
u128, no+, took 1.022965s
u64 , +25, took 1.020189s
u64 , no+, took 0.765725s
```

---

EDIT: After look into the disassemble on `-O2` and `-O3`, the major difference is then on the code generation. (Above reason still hold on -O2 over different test machines/environment yielding slightly different results)

**-O2:**

```
400618:       48 69 d2 93 5b 00 00    imul   $0x5b93,%rdx,%rdx
40061f:       48 83 e8 01             sub    $0x1,%rax
400623:       75 f3                   jne    400618 <_Z4testv+0x18>
```

**-O3:**

```
400628:       66 0f 6f d9             movdqa %xmm1,%xmm3
40062c:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
40062f:       66 0f 6f c1             movdqa %xmm1,%xmm0
400633:       66 0f f4 cc             pmuludq %xmm4,%xmm1
400637:       3d 00 00 00 20          cmp    $0x20000000,%eax
40063c:       66 0f f4 da             pmuludq %xmm2,%xmm3
400640:       66 0f 73 d0 20          psrlq  $0x20,%xmm0
....
```

O3 generate vectorized code while the loop has heavy dependency which cannot get value out of vectorization. It actually generated much more complex code and thus has a much longer timing.

Comment: Thanks that explains it! I should have tried for different gcc parameters before posting.

Comment: Concerning the useless vectorization, [here's a bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70976).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to measure what actually happens at runtime to know for sure.
As [Calvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094101/calvin) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37067436/108517), there are a lot of things going on inside the processor, which will affect the final timing of the loop.

You can use [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/overview/) or [Intel's brilliant tools](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-parallel-studio-xe) to perform the measurements. Intel's tools are expensive but you can try them out for 30 days for free. They are much easier to use than PAPI.